# locally connected space with finite numbers of components

Tags: general-topology

if a locally connected space has finite numbers of components then the space is finite or not?

i know that a compact locally connected space has finite numbers of components.
but when the space is not compact still will  it follow that it has finite components

Comment: The unit interval $[0,1]$ is locally connected and has one component, but is not finite.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. A component is a connected subspace and these can be as large as you like. A simple example: $X = [0,1]$ in the Euclidean topology has **one** component (i.e. it's connected), is locally connected and quite infinite.

It's true that a locally connected compact space $X$ has finitely many *components* (because these then form an open disjoint cover of $X$), but that's a very different thing from saying the space is finite.

A discrete space is locally connected and has as many components as it has points, so maybe you're confused with that?

Comment: Yes sir i am confused wiyh it

Comment: Now i can understand